# how to attach two dictionary RDDs and form a single dictionary rdd to send to kafka topic in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dict obj of the form :-

```
obj = {'owner_id': '3', 'url_id': [1,2,3,4], 'url': ['a','b','c','d'], 'campagin_id': '2'}
```

This dict i am sending from kafka producer to pyspark for data transformation. Now the data i want to form is something like:-

```
new_obj = {"data": {"owner_id": obj['owner_id'], 'campaign_id': {'url': {'1': 'a', '2':'b', '3':'c', '4':'d'}}}
```

I am able to form the url dictionary but now i cant access the owner_id and campaign_id and other data.

```
lines = kafka_stream.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1]))
url_ids = lines.map(lambda line: line['url'])
urls = lines.map(lambda line: line['url_id'])
combine = url_ids.union(urls).reduce(lambda x, y: dict(zip(y, x)))
```

As u can see i want to use both lines RDD and combine RDD in order to form the object I want but I don't know how to combine these two. How to access the owner_id and campaign_id key, value and form the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do something like the following:

```
lines.map(lambda x: {"data": { "owner_id":x['owner_id'], 'campagin_id':{'url':dict(zip(x['url_id'], x['url']))}}}) \
     .collect()

#[{'data': {'owner_id': '3',
#  'campagin_id': {'url': {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}}}}]
```

If you need the actual *campaign_id* instead of *literal campaign_id* in the above 2nd key of `data` dict, just change `'campaign_id'` to `x['campagin_id']` in the code.

Comment: yeah I tried this but the problem with this is that my url and url_id list are very big so spark doesnt zip all of them just three to four elements only. Thats why i had to extract them out and join them separately @jxc

Comment: @PrithviSingh, the `zip` function used in this code is pure python code. Since you already parse the whole data out of json string, it's unlikely to be a memory issue. If you only got 3 to 4 elements out of the zip function, do make sure that lists of both url and url_id have the same size. For your proposed method, in the Spark environment, after partition there is no guarantee that url and its related url_id on another RDD are on the same partition, without an unique_id to link them, your data will be totally mess up.

Comment: yeah url and url_id list are of same size. unique_id to link them? what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @PrithviSingh, your `combine` rdd won't work since the union does not arrange related url and url_id side by side so that you can zip them. reduce is simply not the right function to use here. for the issue with zip function, you will have to add more details why only 3 to 4 get output from zip while you might have like 100 entries in both url and url_id. this is more of a python trouble-shooting problem, not an issues with spark.

Comment: Yeah i got it. so earlier when i was trying to do zip on them only 2 to 4 elements were only coming. But i gave it another go and it worked. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @PrithviSingh, would you mind accept my answer if it worked for your task, thanks and have a good day.